# Update the table name at runtime not working - laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel-4, model, eloquent

This is my model:

```
class Product extends \GlobalModel {
    protected $table = 'product';
}
```

I want to update the table name **oops_product** instead **product** at runtime.

I found **getTable();** to get the table name from model and its working fine:

```
$tableName = with(new Product)->getTable();
```

But when i set the table name using **setTable();** as per [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1716) solution, its not updating the table name.

```
with(new Product)->setTable("oops_produdct");
```

Is there anything wrong?

Help will be appreciated.

edited:

```
$product = new Product(); 
$product->getTable(); // output: product 
$product->setTable("oops_product"); 
$product->getTable(); // output: oops_product
```

now when i run this

```
$product->all();
```

it executes

```
"select * from product"
```

instead of

```
"select * from oops_product"
```

Comment: because $table field is `protected`

Comment: tried this also but not working.

Comment: and did you extend Eloquent class instead of \GlobalModel ?!

Comment: yes, my GlobalModel extends Eloquent

Comment: use that: `$product = new Product; $product->setTable('oops_product');`
you should know that just $product instance will have this table not just all of the instances of Products

Comment: tried this also but still not working btw thanx for the try  soroush gholamzadeh.

Comment: @user3868148 This is working obviously. Show the code you're executing that is not working as expected.

Comment: $product = new Product();
$product->getTable(); // output: product
$product->setTable("oops_product");
$product->getTable(); // output: oops_product
now $product->all(); executes "select * from product" instead of "select * from oops_product"

Comment: please read the edited question @Jarek Tkaczyk

Comment: @user3868148 Now it's all clear. You've got the answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`all()` is a static method that uses brand new instance and calls `get()` on it.

So all you need is using proper method:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->getTable(); // products
$product->setTable('oooops');
$product->get(); // select * from oooops
$product->first(); // select * from oooops limit 1
etc...
```

Just avoid using static Eloquent methods, since they obviously create new instance, that will have default `table` property.

Comment: While this approach works when you initiate a query such as select, it fails when you change the $product (`$product->someProp = 'xyz`;) and want to save it later on (`$product->save();`), as the table of the $product's instance you get from the collection e.g. via `first()` will not be set to the table of the instance that was used for the selection. In order to do this, you'd have to override your model's newInstance so it can be properly hydrated including the table name.

Comment: @Stefan what's the use-case? Even though I provided the answer, now that I look at it, I don't really see any reason to use that myself, so wondering what setup requires such overrides?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk : You may want to change the table when one model should be used to generate different versions of the table e.g. for manual sharding. Like _users_emea_ on connection A, _users_apac_ on connection B. (Maybe also when you operate on a view?). An Eloquent model is strictly bound to a table. However there is `setTable()`, which indicates this could be possible, but then behaves unexpectedly when you query and `save()`.

Answer (score 14):

The problem with the accepted answer is, that modifying the retrieved model instance and later on saving it won't work. See my comment above.

The following trait allows for passing on the table name during hydration.

```
trait BindsDynamically
{
    protected $connection = null;
    protected $table = null;

    public function bind(string $connection, string $table)
    {
        $this->setConnection($connection);
        $this->setTable($table);
    }

    public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false)
    {
        // Overridden in order to allow for late table binding.

        $model = parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists);
        $model->setTable($this->table);

        return $model;
    }

}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use BindsDynamically;
}
```

Applied to the accepted answer:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->getTable(); // products
$product->bind('connection', 'oooops');
$product->get(); // select * from oooops
$product->first(); // select * from oooops limit 1
etc...
$product->myTestProp = 'test;
$product->save(); // now saves into oooops
```

Comment: How to extend this to allow changing any other model property? Like `$fillable`, `$hidden`, `$guarded` etc.

Comment: While I had the use case to bind a model dynamically to a connection/table, I don't see why you would want make `$fillable`, `$hidden`, `$guarded` depend on the connection/table. That would require the user of the model to deal with the model on a per connection/table basis. E.g. you transform a model instance to json and depending on which connection/table it was read from it shows or doesn't show certain attributes. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Let me tell you about my case: I had a model with a lot of calculated fields and used `$appends` to include them into the model. For fetching a single model it's ok, but for fetching a colletion with hundreds, even thousands of models it stats sllowing down the query performance. So in this case, I was looking for a way to disable those calculated fields in certain queries. One note here: when calling these models from a relationship with `with` method, it's not possible to change the `$appends` or any other model property from there.

Comment: Then your trait comes in, I modified it to change the `$appends` property and now, I'm able to set the property as an empty array and get rid of those calculaed fields, by simple doing: `$query->getRelated()->setAppends([]);` before that, this doesn't works!
Then I was looking for a way to make this trait more generic and let it modify any other property in the model. Quite long, but I hope to make my point clear. 

Comment: Sounds to me as if the attribute you added via `$appends` may not be a real attribute, but rather a concept and therefor a class/model on its own, which operates on the model that currently has the attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to change the table name based on my request (my tables would have a prefix based on my request). what I did was that I extended the Model class as MyModel, then I overrode the construct method, combining a table name based on my request and the default table name I provided my models.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{

  public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
  {
      parent::__construct($attributes);
      $this->setTable(Config::get('tablePrefix').$this->getTable());
  }
}
```

which you should replace the Config table prefix towards your approach.

and then in my models I just extended MyModel and all was fine including static calls as I tested.

```
class Category extends MyModel
{

  protected $table = "categories";
}
```

So as my request changed I changed the Config I had provided and could get different table names such as a__categories, b__categories and all was fine including static calls, relations and saving to database.

Comment: I like this approach. I have a question however, how do you handle migrations? Thanks kindly in advance for any insight you might offer.

Comment: @CodeWriter23 Thanks, unfortunately I have not implemented this with migrations, however it might be possible to extend the laravel migrate command and pass a table prefix to the command so we can migrate each group of tables with running migration for each of them, I found a tutorial on extending the command, but I have not tested anything, it might be helpful. https://hackernoon.com/extending-laravels-migration-command-to-add-new-options-90b5a0fc4ef4

Comment: @Merhdad Denghani thanks for your response and the tip, much appreciated. If I have any breakthroughs, I'll share here.

Answer (score 3):

this should work with static methods also (only tested on 5.7)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

function makeModel($table)
{
    $model = new class extends Model
    {
        public static $entryTable;

        public function setTable($table)
        {
            $this->table = static::$entryTable = $table;
        }

        public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
        {
            $static = (new static);
            $static->setTable($static::$entryTable);

            return $static->$method(...$parameters);
        }
    };
    $model->setTable($table);

    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on some of the answers given here.
It is tested on Laravel 8.
Some of the advantages:

- Cannot construct the model from project without supplying the table, one needs to call `DynamicModel::table` to construct an instance
- When Eloquent constructs the model internally the table name is restored without the need to override any other static method
- Static method calls on the model work
- The table name can be changed on the anonymous class retrieved from `DynamicModel::table` and stays the same after that

Usage examples:

```php
$products = DynamicModel::table('oops_produdct');
$products->find(1)->delete(); // deleted record with id 1

$product = $products->first();
$product->prod_name = 'My name';
$product->save(); // first records name changed

$products::all(); // all records in `oops_produdct`

DynamicModel::all(); // gives LogicException
```

Model class:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @mixin Builder
 */
class DynamicModel extends Model
{
    private static array $modelClassToTableMap = [];

    /**
     * Protected constructor to make sure this is called from either
     * DynamicModel::table or internal static methods of Model. Otherwise, we cannot
     * track the class name related to the table
     */
    protected function __construct(array $attributes = [], ?string $table = null)
    {
        if (isset($table)) {
            // use table passed from DynamicModel::table
            $this->setTable($table);
        } elseif (isset(self::$modelClassToTableMap[\get_class($this)])) {
            // restore used table from map while internally creating new instances
            $this->setTable(self::$modelClassToTableMap[\get_class($this)]);
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException('Call DynamicModel::table to get a new instance and be able use any static model method.');
        }

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    public static function table(string $table): self
    {
        return new class([], $table) extends DynamicModel {};
    }

    public function setTable($table): self
    {
        self::$modelClassToTableMap[\get_class($this)] = $table;

        return parent::setTable($table);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you aware of any drawback of your code? I do now know why this solution is more widely used is a game changer as you do not need a file per Model. It reduces the size of the project drammatically. This is pure magic.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this:
Inser this into your Model Class and customize to suit your logic.

```
    public function companies(){
      $instance = Community::of($this->community); //create instance
      $foreignKey = 'id';
      $localKey = 'foreign_id';
      $tableName = $instance->getTable(); //or any logic of yours
      //Here you can dynamically choose the table name, taken from the "HasRelationships.php" File of Laravel
      return $this->newHasMany(
          $instance->newQuery(), $this, $tableName.'.'.$foreignKey,   $localKey
      );
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Call to undefined method App\Model::of()', 'Community' in your case is the parent Model?

Answer (score 0):

Override the following methods in your model:

```php
protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
{
    return tap((new $class())->setTable($this->table), function ($instance) {
        if (!$instance->getConnectionName()) {
            $instance->setConnection($this->connection);
        }
    });
}

public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false): static
{
    return parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists)->setTable($this->table);
}
```

[`newInstance()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/faeb20d3fc61b69790068161ab42bcf2d5faccbc/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L595) allows the query builder created by the model keeps the table name from the original model.

[`newRelatedInstance()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/faeb20d3fc61b69790068161ab42bcf2d5faccbc/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L773) allows you to share the modified table name from `$model->setTable('name')` across all related models, the param `$class` is the class name string of the related model being created.

You might still have to change the table name for the related model since normally you will have related tables with similar but not the same table name (so they are different models).

Personally, my approach is to wrap the invoke on `setTable()` in another method for each related model, then call that wrap method in `newRelatedInstance()`, a real example can be found at https://github.com/n0099/TiebaMonitor/blob/82511a13650fedf7482e7d853ab81101ad0842cf/be/app/Tieba/Eloquent/PostModel.php#L47