# Laravel settable doesn't work as expected

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

**EDIT: Just to save time as some people kindly add response but don't read comments. It appears that although we can set the table on the fly and it works for get and take and all BUT it doesn't work for update.**

Now the original question:

I have a problem with dynamic table name that I can best explain by the code I tried: 
This is what I do and works:

```
$ymodel = new \App\YCenter;
$ymodel->setTable('tableNo1');
$tops = $ymodel->take(10)->get();
var_dump($tops);
```

But this is what I tried:

```
$ymodel = new \App\YCenter;
$ymodel->setTable('tableNo1');

$ymodel->updateOrCreate(
    ['url' => 'heyhey','article_id' => 1],
        ['text'=>'texttext']
);
```

And got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'mydatabase.y_centers' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `y_centers`...
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Edit: **The ideas is to set the table on the fly and that's why Im doing it this way. I don't want to set the table on the model itself.**

Comment: You set 'tableNo1' but the error says it can't find the table 'y_centers'. Did you define a `$table` in your model?

Comment: No Eddy. I didn't because the table is going to change based on the code. Isn't it the whole idea of settable method?

Comment: Yes but the table you are setting and the errors have two different names. Well in the example you provided. Anyways, the error comes from MYSQL itself saying the table does not exist. So my question is, does the table already exist?

Comment: As you can see the name of the tables are the same and Just to make sure I ran the script again.  It seems that settable works for get() and first() but it doesn't work for updateorcreate.

Comment: ok then you can avoid using it then. But in your example, table names are not the same. In your code you wrote `$ymodel->setTable('tableNo1');` but the error reads `'mydatabase.y_centers'`. So it seems 'y_centers' was not found.

Comment: Notice the line $ymodel->setTable('tableNo1'); in both snippets. I set the table name on both to 'tableNo1' but only in updateorcreate I get the error. I just found somewhere else discussing the issue involving taylorotwell herel https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2318 but I'm not sure it's exactly like mine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417794/update-the-table-name-at-runtime-not-working-laravel-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 3):

Some laravel methods make a new instance of an object

This will not work:

```
 $someModel = new RunTimeObject();
 $someModel->setTable('newTable');
 return $someModel->all();
```

This is due to that all() creates a new someModel in the background.
If you use a non-static method: ( for example ->get() )

```
    $runtime = new RunTimeObject();
    $runtime->setTable('newTable');
    return $runtime->get();
```

It will work, so you can only use non static methods