# Laravel 5.7.13 - FirstOrCreate/FirstOrNew not storing value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update a table with two columns 'id' and 'comp_id'. I only want 'comp_id' to exist in the table one time, so I'm using firstOrCreate to do this.

This call is creating a record in the table because the id auto-increment keeps going up every time I try this, but the comp_id value is not being saved.

```
$connections = $connectionTable->where('base_id', $baseId)->get();
$noMatchTable = new noMatch;
foreach($connections as $connection){
 $rec = $noMatchTable->setTable($comparisonId.'_no_match')->firstOrCreate(['comp_id' => $connection->comp_id]);
}
```

I've also tried.

```
 $rec = $noMatchTable->setTable($comparisonId.'_no_match')->firstOrNew(['comp_id' => $connection->comp_id])->save();
```

In both cases $rec->id shows a new id.

Fillable for the model is set correctly

```
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "comp_id"
  ]
```

What frightfully simple thing am I missing?

Comment: Are you certain that `$connection->comp_id` contains a value?

Comment: Yes when I dump it I get the expected value. dump($connection->comp_id);

Comment: Also I've tried hard coding a value. $rec = $noMatchTable->setTable($comparisonId.'_no_match')->firstOrCreate(['comp_id' => 999]);

Comment: I think I found the problem, sadly it's not good news though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is the strangest thing. Every time I run this I get a higher ID, but no entry in the DB table. return DB::connection(config('app.db_connection'))->table("{$id}__no_match")->insertGetId(['comp_id'=> $compId]);

Comment: I was thinking about that, and I'm scratching my head on that one as well. I can't find anything in the work flow from builder->grammer->processor that would not allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some reading on this, and it seems like `updateOrCreate()` in Builder.php calls `firstOrNew()`in the same file. If you look at `firstOrNew()` it will return a new model instance, which means your `setTable()` will not work as the new instance will contain the default table name. I like the solution posted here

[Update the table name at runtime not working - laravel Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417794/update-the-table-name-at-runtime-not-working-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Sadly there is no way to dynamically set a table name and use `updateOrCreate()`